# Where to include third party *.java files into my android app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Possibly a very simple question, but i don't know the answer and it looks like i have not the right words to find the answer myself.

Last 2 weeks I have build my first Android app with Android Studio. Now I want to use a zxing intent for barcode scans. Zxing docs [say](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-Via-Intent) i should use the zxing files `IntentIntegrator.java` and `IntentResult.java` for this.

I could place the files into the folder of my MainActiviy `src/main/java/de/digiscales/scanbrowser`. But i want to do it CORRECT, to stay able to maintain my growing app also in 2 years in an easy way! In which folder of my project should I put such third party .java files?

Or is there a function in Android Studio to include such foreign code?

I have tried to add it as dependency but Gradle says only .JAR files are ok this this.

Comment: you can create a sub-package in your project and keep the files there

Comment: you can create sub folder with in your project or you can add those file into the folder of MainActivity.

Comment: @SaravInfern: I still fought about to do NEW / MODULE / Java Library. Is it this what you mean? Do i have to do this for each file separately? And which library name / Java package name / Java class name i have to use?

Comment: @madhankumar but by MainActivity file is located in src/main/java/de/digiscales/scanbrowser because the package is de.digiscales.scanbrowser. But the package of the Zxing files is com.google.zxing.integration.android. Can it work to put it into src/main/java/de/digiscales/scanbrowser/zxing? And how to import it in my MainActivity?

Comment: @Lutz Hey man if you are going to add only the above mentioned classes just make a sub folder in your project with your desired folder name.Yes, you have create separate files for each for each class and place it in same folder as well.

Comment: @Lutz just copy and past the file or create java class in the name of those files and paste the code to respective .java files.

Comment: The result of doing this were a lot of red underlinings and not working of ALT + ENTER to import classes. now i have tried it with /src/main/java/com/google/zxing/integration/android/ derived from the package name. Looks like this is correct. Now ALT + ENTER works. Anyhow thanks for the try. As you see, it helped me to find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i have used the package name of the files which i wanted to add `com.google.zxing.integration.android` to create this folder structure `src/main/java/com/google/zxing/integration/android/` where I have put the two .java files into.

For me it looks like everything is correct. Android Studio shows no failure. And also using ALT + ENTER works now for importing these classes into my activity.